# How can I make a Python script a drop-in for a Windows executable?

Tags: windows, batch-file

I wrote a little Python script `wrapcl.py` script which wraps our compiler binary (`cl.exe`, the Microsoft Visual Studio C++ compiler). I then created a new batch file `cl.bat` which makes that Python script accessible so that I can run `cl` as before and it will silently call my wrapper script instead of the real program. For what it's worth, here is my `cl.bat` batch file:

```
@python %~dp0\wrapcl.py %*
```

This works quite well - except in one case:

We have existing scripts which do something like

```
cl >NUL 2>&1 && GOTO CL
```

to determine whether the Microsoft Visual Studio C++ compiler is available. This breaks if `cl` actually calls my `cl.bat` batch file since the call to `cl.bat` never returns. We'd have to use `call cl >NUL ...` for that.

Is there any way I can make my `wrapcl.py` Python script look just like `cl.exe` for callers so that I can avoid touching our existing scripts which expect `cl && foo` to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility is to compile your python code as an executable using py2exe.  Here's a link:
[py2exe](http://www.py2exe.org/)